# Neuralnet package in R gives wrong output

Tags: r, algorithm, neural-network

I'm trying to generate prediction of the column "dubina" using this algorithm made in R's "neuralnet" package. But I keep getting non-reliable neural-net output. I have tried changing the number of hidden layers, normalizing and denormalizing data. Is there a mistake in the algorithm, maybe because of the activation function being logistic, not sigmoid?

My dataset:
http://www26.zippyshare.com/v/Nc2Sbuny/file.html

Here is the algorithm:

```
#Data input
podatci<-read.csv("rs5.csv", sep=";", header=T)

#Division into train and test data
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(podatci))
smp_size
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(podatci)), size = smp_size)
train <- podatci[train_ind, ]
test <- podatci[-train_ind, ]
train

#Normalization
train_normal<-(train-min(train))/(max(train)-min(train))
test_normal<-(test-min(test))/(max(test)-min(test))

#Training of the network
install.packages('neuralnet')
library("neuralnet")

n <- names(train_normal)
f <- as.formula(paste("dubina ~", paste(n[!n %in% "dubina"], collapse =  " + ")))
net_tr <- neuralnet(f,data=train_normal,hidden=c(3,2),linear.output=T)

plot(net_tr)

#TESTing of the network

pr.nn<-compute(net_tr, test_normal[,1:2])
ls(pr.nn)
print(pr.nn$net.result)

#Printing
cleanoutput <- cbind(test_normal, as.data.frame(pr.nn$net.result))
colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("x","y","dubina","Neural Net Output")
print(cleanoutput)

#Denormalization of output data
denorm<-(min(test) + cleanoutput* (max(test)-min(test)))
denorm
```

Test sample (part of it, there are 743 data which are split 75/25)

```
          x       y dubina
6   6451993 5057986      0
7   6451993 5055986      0
15  6447993 5063986      0
17  6447993 5059986      0
25  6445993 5059986      0
27  6445993 5055986      0
28  6443993 5073986   1980
29  6443993 5071986   1910
30  6443993 5069986   1700
```

Neural-net output:

```
          x       y dubina Neural Net Output
6   6451993 5057986      0     3180.43153834
7   6451993 5055986      0     3342.40866485
15  6447993 5063986      0     2564.23694019
17  6447993 5059986      0     2888.11216362
25  6445993 5059986      0     2822.94367093
27  6445993 5055986      0     3146.83988044
28  6443993 5073986   1980     1624.49331419
29  6443993 5071986   1910     1786.36349347
30  6443993 5069986   1700     1948.24298143
```

Comment: It is difficult to troubleshoot your problem without reproducible data.  Can you provide your data or another sample dataset that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I've edited the original post and the download link of the data is in it.